# How to get all Enum values in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma

How to retrieve​ all values in enum type in graphql ?

Example:

```
 enum TRUCKPE_NAME {
  TATA_407
  TATA_709
  TATA_1106
  ECHIER_1103
}

type Document {
  truckType: TRUCKPE_NAME
}
```

I want to get all names inside above enum. something like

```
console.log(prisma.Documents().truckType())

// output

TATA_407
TATA_709
TATA_1106
ECHIER_1103
```

Comment: I did something similar via a Typescript based library. Not sure if it would be applicable to GraphQL. Feel free to adapt. `export enum JobStatusGroup {Running,Success,Failure,Pending,Paused,Other} export interface Dictionary {key:string, value:number} export function getKVPairsOfJobStatusGroups(): Dictionary[] {let result:Dictionary[] = [] as Dictionary[];for (let enumMember in JobStatusGroup) {let isValueProperty = parseInt(enumMember, 10) >= 0;if (isValueProperty) {let d:Dictionary={key: JobStatusGroup[enumMember].toString(),value: parseInt(enumMember, 10),}result.push(d);}}return result;}`

Comment: Wouldn't you need an = before the { and commas separating the enum entries too?

Answer (score 6):

```
 query {
  __type(name:"GenderEnum"){
    name
    enumValues{
      name
    }
  }
}
```

credits and more details:
https://medium.com/novvum/how-to-query-enums-with-graphql-using-introspection-daa048014700

Answer (score 4):

You can run an [introspection](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Introspection) query:

```
const { data: { __type: { enumValues } } } = await prisma.request(`
  {
    __type(name: "TRUCKPE_NAME") {
      enumValues {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`)
const values = enumValues.map(({ name }) => name)
```

Comment: is it possible to do something similar with apollo and get all the values of a single enum

Answer (score 0):

Use This Below code for Multiple Enum

```
query MyQuery {
Status: __type(name: "ShipmentStatus") {
  enumValues {
    name
  }
}
ServiceType: __type(name: "DeliveryServiceType") {
  enumValues {
    name
  }
}
```

}