# How to get enums in prisma client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

can I get a list of enums values of a model on the client-side like for select option?

Sample enum

```
enum user_type {
    superadmin
    admin
    user
}
```

I want this as a select-option on the client-side. How can I get them as JSON data?

Comment: another approach using ```graphql``` here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57877222/9339924

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can access the `user_type` enum in your application code like this:

```js
import {user_type } from "@prisma/client";

let foo: user_type = "superadmin";
// use like any other type/enum
```

How you plan to connect this to the client-side or send it there is up to you. Typically Prisma types reside in the server-side of your code, not the client-side, so it might be difficult to import prisma types in your client code directly.

This is how Prisma defines the `user_type` enum under the hood.

```js
// file: node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts
export const user_type: {
  superadmin: 'superadmin',
  admin: 'admin',
  user: 'user'
};
```

You could just copy and paste this into your client-side code if you like.

Answer (score 4):

When you generate Prisma Client, it generates TypeScript interfaces for your models and enum types.

you can do

```
import { PrismaClient, user_type } from '@prisma/client'
```

and this will give you the user_type types declarations