# Importing enum from @prisma/client gives the error "Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Modality'

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to use the Enum I defined in my schema.prisma file in my ORM model (I'm using TypeGraphQL).

My prisma schema is defined as

```
enum Modality {
    CT
    MAMMO
    MRI
    STEREO
}
```

After running `npx prisma generate`, the following TypeScript code generates an error.

```
import { Modality } from "@prisma/client";

> src/schema/ImagingCenter.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'Modality'.
```

I'm able to import PrismaClient and use it just fine in my application, but I'm unable to import any particular types or enums.

I'm on Prisma client ~3.11.0 and have the following in my tsconfig.json:

```
        "target": "es2018",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

Based on this post, it seems like my setup should work fine? [How to get enums in prisma client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579505/how-to-get-enums-in-prisma-client)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have run

```
prisma generate
```

and

```
yarn build
```

I've faced this problem too and these commands can fix