# Cannot import enum from @prisma/client

Tags: prisma, deno, prisma2

So I'm building a telegram bot using [grammY](https://www.grammy.dev/), [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) running on [Deno](https://www.deno.land/). Whilst working on a functionality that requires users to fill in some fields for a form, I decided to use conversations like I always do but this I decided to use Prisma enums for the `conversation.form.select`. But when I tried importing the enum, I get this error:

```bash
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '@prisma/client' does not provide an export named 'BusinessTypeEnum'
import { BusinessTypeEnum } from "@prisma/client";
         ^
    at <anonymous> (file:///home/waptik/code/bots/xxxxx/src/telegram/handlers/conversations/xxxx.conversation.ts:6:10)
```

#### Environment & setup

- OS: Ubuntu
- Database: PlanetScale
- Deno version:  1.30.3
- grammY: 1.13.1

#### Prisma Version

```
4.9.0
```

#### partial conversation.ts

```
import { GrammyContext, GrammyConversation } from "~grammy/context.ts";
import { Composer, createConversation } from "~grammy/deps.ts";
import { handleErrorMessage } from "~grammy/helpers/handleErrors.ts";
import { Prisma, BusinessTypeEnum } from "@prisma/client";


async function createXxxx(convo: GrammyConversation, ctx: GrammyContext) {
  try {
    await ctx.replyWithChatAction("typing");

    const bizTypes = Object.keys(BusinessTypeEnum).map((o) => o);
    console.log({ bizTypes });

  } catch (e) {
    const message = handleErrorMessage(e);
    await ctx.reply(message);
  }
  return;
}
```

#### partial schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["deno"]
  output          = "./generated/client"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}


enum BusinessTypeEnum {
  PRODUCT
  SERVICE
  BOTH
  OTHER
}
```

#### import_map.json

```
{
    "imports": {
        "@/": "./src/",
        "@utils/": "./src/utils/",
        "~grammy/": "./src/telegram/",
        "@prisma/client": "./prisma/generated/client/deno/edge.ts",
        "~prisma": "./prisma/mod.ts",
        "$std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.176.0/",
        "grammy": "https://deno.land/x/grammy@v1.13.1/mod.ts",
        "grammy/types": "https://deno.land/x/grammy@v1.13.1/types.deno.ts",
        "grammy-conversations/": "https://deno.land/x/grammy_conversations@v1.1.1/",
        "menu": "https://deno.land/x/grammy_menu@v1.1.2/mod.ts",
        "zod": "https://deno.land/x/zod@v3.20.5/mod.ts",
    }
}
```

So I'm expecting these values `PRODUCT, SERVICE, BOTH, OTHER` to be printed in console without any errors.
I also tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163378/3342703) as well as deleting `prisma/generated`, `node_modules`, `package***.json` before running `deno run -A --unstable npm:prisma db push && deno run -A --unstable npm:prisma generate --data-proxy` but nothing happened. I created a [github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/18015) but I got no replies, that's why I'm posting here.